# Anyone had any issues getting a disk to start on a Walrus storage sytem?

Tags: cloud, disk-volume, eucalyptus

I'm trying to get a Eucalyptus system up and running and have managed to get the cloud controller and node controller running fine, with an instance running in the cloud system, but without any persistent storage.

When I try and create a volume I get

euca-create-volume -s 10 -z cluster1
VOLUME  vol-5F5D0659    10      creating        2010-05-31T09:10:11.408Z

but when I try and see the volume I get

euca-describe-volumes
VOLUME  vol-5F5D0659     10             cluster1        failed  2010-05-31T09:10:11.408Z
VOLUME  vol-5FE9065E     10             cluster1        failed  2010-05-31T09:02:56.721Z

I've dug all over the place, but can't seem to turn up a reason the creation would fail or where to start looking to see what the issue might be.  Anyone have any ideas where to even start looking for the answer to this?

Ta

Peter.

Comment: We need more info: What's the servers arrangement? What's you network mode(VNET-MODE)? Also, since it's been 12 months, have you made new progress on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We gave up on Eucalyptus entirely due to some issues (probably more to do with Ubuntu's implementation than anything) and then tried openVZ (also stopped using) and eventually settled on KVM which has been rock solid for us.

Thanks.

Peter.